# Accessing @ConfigurationProperties Values in a Utility Class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an `@ConfigurationProperties` class called `AppProperties` that contains application property values. I want to access one of these properties, specifically `stringValue`, from a utility class named `MyUtil`.

Here's my `AppProperties` class:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app")
@Data
public class AppProperties {
    private List<String> listValue;
    private boolean booleanValue = true;
    private String stringValue;
}
```

And this is my `MyUtil` class:

```
@Slf4j
public class MyUtil {

    private MyUtil() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public static String doJob() {
        log.debug(stringValue); // How can I access the `stringValue` from here?
    }
}
```

My `MyUtil` class has a private constructor, making it impossible to instantiate, so dependency injection (DI) isn't an option.

How can I access the `stringValue` property from `MyUtil`? Is it possible to do this without changing the utility class structure?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As MyUtil isn't a Spring bean, you cannot inject properties. You can however pass the string value or the AppProperties object as an argument when invoking the method.

Comment: Not possible what are you asking for.

Comment: I'm with @NicoVanBelle. The simplest way is to just pass the object or value as argument.

Comment: Accessing `Spring Beans` inside non-spring managed classes is possible by implementing the [ApplicationContextAware interface](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html). Then `myClassThatImplementsApplicationContextWare.getBean("AppProperties.class")` can be used to access the registered spring bean. i.e., all properties configured. [You can find a similar example here](https://confluence.jaytaala.com/display/TKB/Super+simple+approach+to+accessing+Spring+beans+from+non-Spring+managed+classes+and+POJOs).

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to modify the `MyUtil` class to load properties. There is no other way that you can inject properties automatically in MyUtil.

**Note:** If you want to load the properties without **Spring Dependency Injection**, then use the below code.

Update the class to this:

```
@Slf4j
public class MyUtil {

    private static final Properties properties = new Properties();

    static {
        ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        InputStream input = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("application.properties");
        try {
            properties.load(input);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private MyUtil() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public static String doJob(String property) {
        log.debug(properties.getProperty(property));
        return "...";
    }
}
```

Just pass the key from the class from where you are calling by passing the property `MyUtils.doJob(property)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot use a private variable from another class in this class,or I wonder if you can make the stringValue as a class variable,because class variable is owned by class instead of object.Using 'static' to make it to be a class variable.I hope this can help you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).